# NoSuchFileException when running jar file

Tags: java, runtimeexception

When I run a jar file that accesses other files in the `src` directory, I get the following `RuntimeException`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>   src\FileToBeAccessed.txt.lck
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
>           at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.logging.FileHandler.(Unknown Source)
>           at Program.main(Program.java:30)

The code works fine when I run it directly without building a jar file.

Comment: Does that file exist ? Is the path correct ?

Comment: The src directory won't exist once the program is exported to a jar, any resources will packaged into the jar file itself, meaning you can no longer treat them like a File, but will need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` depending on your needs. This gets asked a few times a day, so you do some searching, I'm sure you'll find some answers which will help you out

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't find anything, but thank you, I think I'm able to fix it now

Comment: @Shreyas Chavan click on "jar file"

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599138/how-to-access-and-read-a-txt-file-from-a-runnable-jar)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was looking for 'NoSuchFileException'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change how you access resources in a jar to a stream.

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is really strange that

```
this.getClass().getResource("file.txt")
```

does work in IDE but NOT when you run it from a jar.

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt")
```

works both inside IDE and from jar.