# Java Swing Gui is not able to read data from the file inside the runnable jar

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface, jar

Okay, so I'm having a problem where once I export my Java Swing project into a runnable jar file one part of the feature I coded does not function at all. Which is to read the file "TryndaUpdate101720.tsv". It works fine when I test it out in IDE eclipse but once it's exported it's not able to function as in the test environment.

I have looked up this problem and couldn't find any solution. There is another way I can make it so it read the "TryndaUpdate101720.tsv" but it's not user friendly because I have to include the "TryndaUpdate101720.tsv" outside of the runnable jar file and have to take input from the user to get the path of it. Which I really don't want to do.

Implementation of reading the file code:

```
allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(this.getClass().getResource("/sim/resources/TryndaUpdate101720.tsv").getPath()));
```

This is the error I'm getting when I run the exported runnable jar file. I have bolded the error to indicate that is the file path where the code break. My guess is because of "!" in the file path.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: **file:\C:\Users\ssimr\Downloads\TryndaMatchUpGui.jar!\sim\resources\TryndaUpdate101720.tsv (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)**
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:153)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:108)
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
    **at sim.gui.WhichChamp.getChampFromTSV(WhichChamp.java:217)**
    at sim.gui.Expertimentgui$4.mouseClicked(Expertimentgui.java:368)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6379)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4990)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4919)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4557)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2769)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4822)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the resource as a Stream to *read* the file from your JAR. Here is an example to read a text file as a stream. Also, make sure your file path is correct because that can be a problem.

```java
//static URL url = ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/sim/resources/TryndaUpdate101720.tsv");
//InputStreamReader file = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
static InputStream in = ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/sim/resources/TryndaUpdate101720.tsv");

public static void readTxtFile(String content) {
        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            //FileReader file = new FileReader(filename);
            //InputStreamReader file = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
            //System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("TryndaUpdate101720.tsv");
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            
            String line = br.readLine();
            int i = 0;
            while(line != null) {
                if(line.equals(content)) {
                    System.out.println("Expected input equals actual text!");
                    break;
                }
                line = br.readLine();
                i++;
            }
            
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println("Exception occurred in readTxtFile.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599138/how-to-access-and-read-a-txt-file-from-a-runnable-jar)

Comment: @Simran glad it helped. As MadProgrammer said, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of build tools you are using.
The file you want to access , may not included in the jar or included but in a different location.

Eclipse and some IDE will run the app from the project location, so it will able to run without issue.

Check documents for you tool , ant, maven, gradle etc for how to include resources in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Pranav Amarnath I was able to resolve my problem. So instead of using **FileReader** I used **BufferedReader** with **getResourceAsStream** to get the file inside the jar file.

Before:

```
allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(this.getClass().getResource("/sim/resources/TryndaUpdate101720.tsv").getPath()));
```

After:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sim/resources/TryndaUpdate101720.tsv"); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
allRows = parser.parseAll(reader);
```

Comment: Then you should upvote and mark Pranav Amarnath answers as "accepted"

Comment: You're right. I thought I have to make a new instance of BufferedReader inside of parseAll.